# Which file is changed after I do "make menuconfig"?

Tags: kernel, makefile

In linux, I thought that the file `Makefile` is changed after I run `make menuconfig`.

But when I diff `Makefile`, I don't see any difference.

Which file is changed after I do `make menuconfig`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, after a `make menuconfig` or `make config`, the `.config` file is changed. This file describes which options are choosen and will tell make and Makefile which file to compile and which options to activate.

As said by @Lekensteyn, the previous config file will be renamed in `.config.old`

Comment: It may be useful to know that the previous .config file (before running targets like `menuconfig`) is moved to `.config.old`.

Answer (score 11):

In general, you may use

```
find /usr/src/linux -mmin -10
```

to find files, modified in the last 10 Minutes yourself in said directory. This would lead to the result Cédric Julien gave: .config.